# Prove that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\le\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, contest-math, uvw

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that
> $$\dfrac{1}{a^2+2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2+2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2+2}=\dfrac{1}{3}.$$
> Show that
> $$\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\le\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{7}}.$$

My try: since
$$\dfrac{1}{2+a^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1-\dfrac{a^2}{a^2+2}\right)$$
so
$$\dfrac{a^2}{a^2+2}+\dfrac{b^2}{b^2+2}+\dfrac{c^2}{c^2+2}=\dfrac{7}{3}$$
we only prove

$\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\le\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{7}}$

and I want use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove it,But I can't works,such
$$\left(\dfrac{a^2}{a^2+2}+\dfrac{b^2}{b^2+2}+\dfrac{c^2}{c^2+2}\right)(a^2+2+b^2+2+c^2+2)\ge (a+b+c)^2$$
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2+6)\ge \dfrac{3}{7}(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac)$$
$$\Longrightarrow 4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+42\ge 6(ab+bc+ac)$$
and let $$p=a+b+c,q=ab+bc+ac,r=abc$$
so
$$2p^2+21\ge 7q$$
and we only prove
$$\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}=\dfrac{ab+bc+ac}{abc}=\dfrac{q}{r}\le\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{7}}$$
maybe this is not true.

But this not usefull to solve this problem .

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}>\frac{3}{\sqrt7}$, $\frac{1}{a}=\frac{kx}{\sqrt7}$, $\frac{1}{b}=\frac{ky}{\sqrt7}$ and $\frac{1}{c}=\frac{kz}{\sqrt7}$, where $k>0$ and $x+y+z=3$.

Hence, $k>1$ and $\frac{1}{3}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2+2}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{7}{k^2x^2}+2}>\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{7}{x^2}+2}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{7+2x^2}$,

which is a contradiction because we'll prove now that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{7+2x^2}\geq\frac{1}{3}$.

Indeed, let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that 
$$4x^2y^2x^2+\sum\limits_{cyc}(8x^2y^2+7x^2)-49\geq0$$ or
$$4w^6+8(9v^4-6uw^3)u^2+7(9u^2-6v^2)u^4-49u^6\geq0$$
or $f(w^3)\geq0$, where $f(w^3)=2w^6-24u^3w^3+7u^6-21u^4v^2+36u^2v^4$.

We see that $f'(w^3)=4w^3-24u^3<0$, which says that it's enough to prove that

$f(w^3)\geq0$ for a maximal value of $w^3$, which happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $y=x$ and $z=3-2x$.

Hence, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{7+2x^2}\geq\frac{1}{3}\Leftrightarrow(x-1)^2(2x-1)^2\geq0$.

Done!

Also we can use the Vasc's LCF Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

An analytical proof is proposed below :

[image]

Comment: first,Thank you for your answer,I think this inequality have without analysis methods,I like deal inequality use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,AM-GM,Holder,and other.

Comment: @ china math : You should have stated that you don't want any method but a particular one. Also, I like the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Nevertheless I use another method in the cases where the calculus is easier.

Comment: @JJacquelin Your solution is wrong, because the equality occurs not for $a=b=c$ only. See my solution.

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM, $1=\dfrac{3}{a^2+2}+\dfrac{3}{b^2+2}+\dfrac{3}{c^2+2} \geq \dfrac{9}{\sqrt[3]{(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)}}$

By AM-GM, $7 = \dfrac{3a^2}{a^2+2}+\dfrac{3b^2}{b^2+2}+\dfrac{3c^2}{c^2+2} \geq \dfrac{9\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{\sqrt[3]{(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)}}$

As everything is positive, we can safely divide the inequalities with each other.

$\dfrac{7}{1} \geq \dfrac{\dfrac{9\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{\sqrt[3]{(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)}}}{\dfrac{9}{\sqrt[3]{(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)}}}$

$\Rightarrow 7 \geq (abc)^{\dfrac{2}{3}}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} \geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{7}}$

By AM-GM, $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c} \geq \dfrac{3}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}\geq \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{7}}$

$\therefore \dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c} \geq \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{7}}$

Comment: $1 \ge 0.5$ and $0.5 \ge 0.1$ does not imply $1/0.5 \ge 0.5/0.1$

Comment: I was thinking about that... Do you know of a way to prevent that case from arising?

Comment: if  $cd \gt 0$ then $ad -bc \ge 0$ would imply $\frac{a}{c} \ge \frac{b}{d}$

Comment: This answer is wrong. $7 \geq (abc)^{2/3}$ is wrong. For example, $a = 3, b = 3/2, c = \frac12\sqrt{553}$, then $\frac{1}{a^2+2}+\frac{1}{b^2+2}+\frac{1}{c^2+2}=\frac{1}{3}$, however $(abc)^{2/3} > 14 > 7$.

Comment: The problem is to prove $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\le\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}$. However, this answer is to prove $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq \frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative proof, without using uvw*:

Let $x = \frac{\sqrt 7}{a},
y = \frac{\sqrt 7}{b}, z = \frac{\sqrt 7}{c}$. We have
$x, y, z > 0$ and
$$\frac{1}{2x^2 + 7}
+ \frac{1}{2y^2 + 7} + \frac{1}{2z^2 + 7} = \frac13. \tag{1}$$
We need to prove that
$$x + y + z \le 3. $$

WLOG, assume that $x \le y \le z$.
Let $w = \frac{x + y}{2}$.

**Fact 1**: $x + y \le 2$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

**Fact 2**: It holds that
$$\frac{1}{2x^2 + 7}
+ \frac{1}{2y^2 + 7} \le 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2w^2 + 7}.$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

By Fact 2 and (1), we have
$$2 \cdot \frac{1}{2w^2 + 7} + \frac{1}{2z^2 + 7} \ge \frac13$$
or
$$\frac{2(2w^2z^2 + 4w^2 + z^2 - 7)}{3(2w^2+7)(2z^2+7)} \le 0.$$
Thus, we have
$$2w^2z^2 + 4w^2 + z^2 - 7 \le 0$$
or
$$2(wz - 1)^2 + (2w + z)^2 \le 9$$
which results in
$$2w + z \le 3$$
that is
$$x + y + z \le 3.$$

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

From (1) and $x \le y \le z$, we have
$$\frac{1}{2x^2 + 7} + \frac{1}{2y^2 + 7} \ge \frac29$$
or
$$\frac{8x^2y^2 + 10x^2 + 10y^2 - 28}{9(2x^2+7)(2y^2+7)} \le 0$$
or
$$8x^2y^2 + 10x^2 + 10y^2 - 28 \le 0.$$
Using $x^2y^2 + 1 \ge 2xy$, we have
$$8(2xy - 1) + 10x^2 + 10y^2 - 28 \le 0$$
or
$$16xy + 10x^2 + 10y^2 - 36 \le 0$$
or
$$8(x + y)^2 + 2x^2 + 2y^2 - 36 \le 0$$
Using $2x^2 + 2y^2 \ge (x + y)^2$, we have
$$9(x + y)^2 \le 36$$
or
$$x + y \le 2.$$

We are done.

*Proof of Fact 2*:

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{2x^2+7} - \frac{1}{2w^2 + 7} \le \frac{1}{2w^2+7} - \frac{1}{2y^2 + 7}$$
or
$$\frac{2(w-x)(w + x)}{(2x^2+7)(2w^2+7)} \le \frac{2(y - w)(y + w)}{(2w^2+7)(2y^2+7)}$$
or (using $w - x = y - w = (y-x)/2 \ge 0$)
$$\frac{w + x}{2x^2+7} \le \frac{y + w}{2y^2+7}$$
or
$$\frac{(y - x)(2wx + 2wy + 2xy - 7)}{(2y^2+7)(2x^2+7)} \le 0$$
or
$$2wx + 2wy + 2xy - 7 \le 0$$
or
$$(x + y)^2 + 2xy - 7\le 0$$
which is true using $x + y \le 2$ (Fact 1).

We are done.

Comment: It's a shame the downvoter did not explain the vote. I would like to upvote but I have not finished working through this yet.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Thank you.

Comment: I am about 1/2 way down this now, it takes me a while to read your answers. I left the comment as a reminder to myself to finish this.

Comment: @RiverLi I learn from you so (+1).

Comment: @ErikSatie Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

This might not be the "proper" way, but it can be seen that both the expressions are symmetrical in all terms. And we need the maximum of the second eqn. This can happen only when all the terms contribute equally to the sum, if it were not so then, let 1/a<1/b<1/c, then we can make b and c to a, and get higher sum. So, putting it back in the first eqn. we get $ \frac{3}{a^2+2} = 1/3$, solving which we get $ a = \sqrt{7}$ or $-\sqrt{7} $. Choosing the positive root, as we need maximum values, we get $ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}$

Missed JJacquelin's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/108514/jjacquelin), by a few minutes. It is more analytical, than mine.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I am new here. It would help me for future answers.

Comment: Compensate with my +1